# Must unit tests be independent if the setup time is not insignificant?

Tags: unit-testing

Exactly how independent should unit tests be? What should be done in a "before" section of a unit testing suite?

Say, for example, I am testing the functionality of a server - should the server be created, initialised, connected to it's various data sources, &c. inside the body of *every* test case. Are there situations where it may be appropriate to initialise the server once, and then test more than one case.

The other situation I am considering is mobile app testing - where the phone objects need to be created to perform a unit test. Should this be done *every* time. Create phone, initialise, run test, destroy phone, repeat?

Comment: Consider rephrasing the title in context to the specific question asked at the end. The theoretical answer is "separate enough that they do not interfere with each other" .. but a practical answer is usually more useful. (Bringing up a phone emulate for each unit test would increase the runtime to "unbearable".)

Comment: This is a general problem.. The example of mobile app testing is just that, an example.

Comment: But it's not a *practical* problem without context and the answer (apart from the obvious theoretical answer) *depends* upon context - which is why I suppose it was down-voted. In any case, if the code is well designed (i.e. no singletons or shared state) then the "setup" should be able to quickly bring everything *relevant* up to a base-state (remember that there is a distinction between unit and integration tests).

Comment: s'pose.. I'll modify the title

Comment: It seems like you are writing integration tests - i.e. verifying that an entire subsystem works as expected. In this case, use your judgment.. Ideally you'd like each test to be not affected by any other. However to minimize execution time, if you can make groups of tests that can share setup.. No reason not to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unit tests should be completely independent, i.e. each should be able to run in any order so each will need to have its own initialization steps.

Now, if you are talking about server or phone initialization, it sounds more like integration tests rather than unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally yes.  Every test should start from scratch, and put the system into a particular well-defined state before executing the function under test. If you don't, then you make it more difficult to isolate the problem when the test fails.  Even worse, you may cause the test not to fail because of some extra state left behind by an earlier test.

If you have a situation where the setup time is too long, you can mock or stub some of the ancillary objects.

If you are worried about having too much setup code, you can refactor the setup code into reusable functions.